# Removing 0 values when labelling integer field using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, vbscript

I am trying to do a simple labelling exercise.

However, I am a bit stuck on how to remove unwanted '0' values.  I have three fields which I would like to display in a stacked label i.e. on three lines.  However the third field has a number of 0 values which I would like to disappear - i.e. instead of having:

```
Field One
Field Two
0
```

I would like to have:

```
Field One
Field Two
Blank
```

Answer (score 8):

Next to the label field click the "expression" button, then "advanced" checkbox and write a function in VBScript, JScrip or Python (choose the parser at the bottom). In this case 0 is an integer, if '0' use that. The Verify button tests it.

It expects a return called "FindLabel" so you have to use that name.

Here is a VBScript example

```
Function FindLabel ( [Field1] , [Field2] , [Field3])
If [Field3] <> 0 Then 
FindLabel = [Field1] & " " & [Field2] & " " & [Field3]
Else FindLabel = [Field1] & " " & [Field2]
End If
End Function
```

The label field will then show `<expression>` and the label will be "Field1 Field2 field3" if Field3 is not equal to 0, and "Field1 Field2" if it is.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about creating a label expression.

Advice is given in the help at [Building label expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000) but there is also someone's teaching material at [Mastering Expressions](http://www.teachmegis.com/outlines/Mastering%20Expressions%20-%20PUG%202011.pdf) which looks helpful.